# pngData back to UIImage

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

I have a `UIImage` variable, `a`. I would like to use it within my app as a .png data file. How do I go about recasting `a` back into a `UIImage` for use?

How can I cast this data object back into a `UIImage`?

```
let pngImage = a!.pngData()
```

Comment: your question isn't clear. Are you saying that you have a UIImage, you then want to turn the UIImage into png image data and then take that png image data and turn it back into a different UIImage?

Comment: you can use init of UIImage,        `if let data = your_pngData {
            let image = UIImage(data: data)
        }`

Answer (score 3):

Converting UIImage to PNG Data:

```
extension UIImage {

    // UIImage to Data (PNG Representation)
    var PNGData: Data? {
        return UIImagePNGRepresentation(self)
    }
}
```

Using your example:

```
let a = UIImage("foo") // Sample image named foo
```

UIImage to Data:

```
let pngData = a.data
```

Data to UIImage:

```
let pngImage = UIImage(data: pngData)
```

Comment: The OP is clearly using iOS 12 and the new `pngData` property of `UIImage`. No need for the first half of your answer. The very last line of your answer is all that the OP is looking for.